# C# string[] to int[]

Tags: c#, string, arrays, parsing, int

Is there a way to convert string arrays to int arrays as easy as parsing an string to an int in C#.

```
int a = int.Parse(”123”);
int[] a = int.Parse(”123,456”.Split(’,’)); // this don't work.
```

I have tried using extension methods for the int class to add this functionality myself but they don't become static.

Any idea on how to do this fast and nice?

Comment: LINQ ought allow you to do this in a single line. Or lambda expressions.

Comment: Did you try to search this site before you asked?

Answer (score 18):

This linq query should do it:

```
strArray.Select(s => int.Parse(s)).ToArray()
```

Answer (score 8):

```
int[] a = Array.ConvertAll("123,456".Split(','), s => Int32.Parse(s));
```

Should do just fine. You could modify the lambda to use TryParse if you don't want exceptions.

Comment: `Array.ConvertAll` definitely requires fewer reallocations than LINQy `ToArray()`.  Note that in this case, you don't even need a lambda, you can pass `Int32.Parse` as the second parameter of `ConvertAll`.

Answer (score 6):

```
int[] a = "123,456".Split(’,’).Select(s => int.Parse(s)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
”123,456”.Split(’,’).Select( s => int.Parse(s) ).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this :

```
"123,456".Split(',').Select(s => int.Parse(s)).ToArray()
```

Answer (score 3):

I think, like that:

```
string[] sArr = { "1", "2", "3", "4" };
int[] res = sArr.Select(s => int.Parse(s)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the extension method.  This is done on string, because you can't add a static function to a string.

```
public static int[] ToIntArray(this string value)
{
    return value.Split(',')
        .Select<string, int>(s => int.Parse(s))
        .ToArray<int>();
}
```

Here is how you use it

```
string testValue = "123, 456,789";

int[] testArray = testValue.ToIntArray();
```

This assumes you want to split on ',' if not then you have to change the ToIntArray

Comment: Very awesome, just what I was looking for.  Thanks!